# Found character instead of field delimiter '|' in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a row in my CSV file like mentioned below

"TEXT"|"123584543"||||"Sherly"||"E'Sheryl"|||"DOCT"||"DC"|||||"AC"|||||||||||

I am trying to create stage using the below query:

```
Create or Replace file format test_stg
type = CSV
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
FIELD_DELIMITER = '|'
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042'
SKIP_HEADER=1
empty_field_as_null = true
ESCAPE = '"';

When I run the above query I'm getting error which I have mentioned below:

**SQL compilation error: value [\"] for parameter 'FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY' conflict with parameter 'ESCAPE'**
```

When I try the below query, it is getting executed successfully.

```
create or replace file format test_stg1
  type = csv
  record_delimiter = '\n'
  field_delimiter = '|'
  skip_header = 1
  null_if = ('NULL', 'null')
  empty_field_as_null = true
  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '0x22';
```

This query gets executed successfully. But when I run the COPY command, I'm getting an unusual error  - Found character instead of field delimiter '|'.

Can anyone guide in fixing this issue?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is your source file encoded in UTF-8? If not, you may need to set the `encoding` option on your file format. This is one reason to see this error. The supported encodings are on this page (scroll about halfway down) https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

Comment: Yes the source file is encoded in UTF-8

Comment: I believe the first statement would be fine if you removed the `escape = '"'` or made it `escape = NONE`.  The issue appears to be that your escape and your field_optionally_enclosed_by are the same character.  Based on your example, you don't need to define an escape character.

Comment: I'm still getting error that says - Found character 'D' instead of field delimiter '|'

Answer (score 1):

Remove the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '0x22' ,recreate file format and run the copy statement.